# Vue on LG WebOS

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, webos

I am choose Vue to develop a web app for LG WebOS TV but get an issue. The problem is that router doesn't rendering anything and there is no errors in console, but same app works as it should with desktop browser. I know that problem is with router but can't figure out why, especially when `vue-snotify` renders without any problem.I tried different babel presets without any result. Maybe somebody faced the same issue?

my Vue setup:

```
vue: 2.5.21 
vue-router: 3.0.2
vuex: 3.0.1
```

babel:

```
presets: [
  @babel/preset-env
],
plugins: [
  [@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators, {legacy: true}],
  [@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties, {loose: true}]
]
```

WebOS device userAgent:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Web0S; Linux/SmartTV) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.34 Safari/537.36 WebAppManager
```

Comment: How can you see console on LG smart tv ? can you help me please ?

Comment: WebOS IDE provides on device app test, after app start you will see Chromium console.

Answer (score 0):

I do use Vue for LG WebOS project almost without any problems.
For the moment I use Vue.js v2.6.0-beta.1 ... Ive tried to use latest stable release of Vue but had unpredictable problems with and had to return to v2.6.0-beta.1 it seams that it's  quite stable for my project.

vue-router v3.0.2
vuex v3.1.0
vuex-router-sync v4.3.1
vue-resource v1.5.1

Propobly you need to provide a part of source code for better understanding

Comment: can you provide a helpful guide for using it with LG Web OS ?